# how does eth-lightwallet manage transaction nonces?

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, eth-lightwallet

I am using eth-lightwallet 2.4.3. I found some of my transactions never got mined. Using txpool.status I noticed I was getting a number in queued.

```
txpool.status

{
 pending: 0,
 queued: 2
}
```

I understand that transactions in queued are there because they have a nonce that is out of sequence.

This problem doesn't always happen. Sometimes everything works ok.

How and where in the code does eth-lightwallet manage the nonce? I presume it must have a technique for knowing what the next nonce value will be for each transaction.

I should mention I am using eth-lightwallet with the hooked-web3-provider and use the web3 api.

Answer (score 3):

[In this example](https://github.com/ConsenSys/eth-lightwallet/blob/master/example/example_usage.js) the nonce has do be added manually. So I assume that you have to handel the nonce yourself in the light client.

```
// TX to register the key 123
txOptions.to = contractData.addr
txOptions.nonce += 1
var registerTx = txutils.functionTx(abi, 'register', [123], txOptions)
var signedRegisterTx = signing.signTx(keystore, pwDerivedKey, registerTx, sendingAddr)
```

Comment: I should have mentioned I am using hooked-web3-provider.